# How to control desktop colour?

Tags: settings, system-settings

After upgrading to 16.04, my nice purple desktop stopped being entirely purple. After today's batch of security etc. fixes, my desktop is now royal blue.

I'm not seeing any way to control colour in the "settings" app. This may be because the "displays" tab simply tells me "could not get screen information".

Is there any way to set a desktop background and general colour scheme in Ubuntu's default window manager, or am I entirely at the whim of the developers?

Update - when I rebooted, I got back the ugly mix of purple and red that came with the upgrade to 16.04. So at least there wasn't an intentional colour change made mid-release.

Answer (score 0):

you can control you desktop background color from the "setting" app in the appearance section.

The fastest way to access the appearance settings is to type appearance in the launcher and then select the appearance item.

in the **look** tab of the appearance setting you should be able to select wall paper and also change the desktop background color, from the color selector, there you can select your preferred color or background image or gradient(you will see this option at the top right section of the tab immediately above the wallpaper section).

Additionally, you can also select the wall the behavior tab to access the behavior settings.

For more display settings, you can install unity-tweak-tool, which which help you select and change theme and perform some other display setting that are not available on the appearance option.
you can install unity tweak tool using the command below:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```